# Phalcon form validation messages

Tags: forms, validation, phalcon

There are some misunderstandings about how the messaging works for the Forms in Phalcon. Say we have a form and trying to add some extended error message for one of fields named 'code' in controller:

`$form = new SampleForm();`

Implementation of SampleForm is done in a corresponding class through `initialize` and the `code` element is `$code = new \Phalcon\Forms\Element\Text('code');`

The next code adds the message :

`$form->get('code')->appendMessage(new \Phalcon\Validation\Message("The Code desn\'t exist or not valid"));`

but trying to receive this message like

`$form->getMessagesFor('code')`

gives me nothing (the dump):

`Phalcon\Validation\Message\Group Object
(
    [_position:protected] => 
    [_messages:protected] => 
)`

Another attempt via

`$form->get('code')->getMessages()`

gives (the dump):

`Phalcon\Validation\Message\Group Object
(
    [_position:protected] => 
    [_messages:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Phalcon\Validation\Message Object
                (
                    [_type:protected] => 
                    [_message:protected] => The Code desn\'t exist or not valid
                    [_field:protected] => 
                    [_code:protected] => 0
                )
         )
)`

My question: what am I doing wrong and why `$form->[get/has]MessagesFor($name)` doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell you, form handling is really poorly implemented and messed up in Phalcon, as I can see now, after a few months work.

In this case, you have multiple `getMessage` functions and they DO NOT return the same value. Even some of them returns a reference and some of them returns a copy of the error messages, and if you are appending messages to the copy, they won't be available elsewhere through the `getMessage` functions.
This even changed form version 1.2 to 1.3, we had a hard time figuring out which functions should we use. If you like, you could check out the C code behind this, in the [Phalcon repository](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/tree/master/ext), it has been a great help for me to figure out why things don't work the way I expected.

My advices is, print the values of getMessage functions: `Form::getMessages()`, `Form::getMessagesFor()`, `Form::get('element_name')->getMessages()`. Then try appending new messages to them and print them again. See which one contains your messages.
I ended up getting messages for Phalcon's built in validation classes by `$form->get('email')->getMessages()` and getting my own added in the controller by `$form->getMessagesFor('email')`. I am still searching for a solution to get all the messages in one place.

Comment: Did you find a way around this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Serin is right, messages are saved into different objects, so i came up with getting all of those like this

```
<?php foreach ($form as $element) {
                //Get any generated messages for the current element
                foreach ([$form->getMessagesFor($element->getName()), $element->getMessages()] as $messages) {
                    if (count($messages)) {
                            //Print each element
                            foreach ($messages as $message) {
                                    echo $message;
                            }
                    }
                }
        }?>
```

Let's hope easier method will be added in nearest future: